# How to find period of $f$ if $f(x+13) + f(x+630) = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ be a periodic function with period $T$. The question was to find the (fundamental) period given the following relation.
$$ f(x+13) + f(x+630) = 0 $$

Now, the given method is:
$$\begin{align} 
&f(x+13) + f(x+630) = 0 \\
\implies &f((x+617)+13) + f((x+617)+630) = 0 \\
\implies &f(x+630) + f(x+1247) = 0 \\
\end{align}$$

Subtracting this equation from the 'original', we have:
$$ f(x+1247) = f(x+13) $$

So, the period is $ 1234 $.

All this is fine. However, my doubt is this: *How do we know that $1234$ is the **fundamental** and not just any period*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prime factors of $1234$ are $2$ and $617$. Since $f(x+617)=-f(x)$, $617$ isn't a period, and we need only rule out $2$. In fact it appears to me that $2$ *could* be the fundamental period of $f$: just take $f(x)=\sin\pi x$, for instance.. (And that's assuming that the period is an integer, which of course it need not be.)

Comment: Oh. So there's no way in which we can find the fundamental period? I am asking this because this was a part of another question and that question was worded like: "If $T$ is *the* period, what is $T + \lambda$...". The wording suggests that they mean the fundamental period.

Comment: @Parth: No, there’s no way to find the fundamental period; you can only limit the possibilities.

Comment: Well then, the wording is bad (of the question). Thanks for the answer! :D

Comment: @Parth: You’re welcome! (It wouldn’t be the first badly worded question — or the last!)

Answer (score 2):

We don't. We could as well have $1234=nT$ with some $n\in\mathbb N$. However, as long as $f$ is not the zero function, we know that $617$ is *not* a multiple of $T$, but that only gives us that $n$ must be odd.